# How do I keep WZZIP from creating a zip that makes a folder when unzipped?

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking at an automated process (utilizing a "DOS" .BAT file) that creates zip files with a simple command like...

wzzip [path][zip file name] [files to be zipped]

...but when a partner receives and unzips these files, it's creating a folder with the name of the zip file and putting the files inside it, and they need (well, or at least prefer) it to just extract the files to the "." folder.

Is there a way to get wzzip to use "." instead of creating an eponymous folder?  The only thing I could see in the options list was to maybe hack something out of -r-p (even though I DON'T actually want it to recurse folders when zipping), but I was hoping there might be a better way.

The partner company is apparently running Linux, so while I see that wzunzip has an option to set the output folder that MIGHT override the default behavior, I'm not sure what the app they are using might allow.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code of your batch file I can only suggest the obvious: change current directory inside the folder before wzzip: `cd /d "somepath" & wzzip "zip file name" *` which should add the files from current directory with a relative path without the base folder.

Comment: The code is essentially above, but if you something more concrete, it's like this:

wzzip c:\NewData\Data20150819.zip File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt

The problem is that when you unzip this, you get the files put in a new folder, Data20150819, instead of put in the current folder.

Comment: Well, so what happens if you follow the suggestion from the above comment #1?

Comment: The above doesn't address my issue, so no I didn't run it initially; but now I have, and there's no change.  The problem, is no matter what folder the zip file is in, when I try to extract the files, it extracts them into a new directory (.\[zipfilename]) instead of the current directory (.).

Comment: Try using a more sane zipping utility then? The question belongs to superuser.com btw.

Comment: That may be the only option, but will require more effort, which is why I thought I'd ask about options I maybe missed or didn't understand.

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://www.winzip.com/ and download the Winzip Command Line utilities. Install and use `WZZIP.EXE`.

Comment: I'm using wzzip.exe; I'm asking how I can change it's default behavior -- I didn't see any options that seemed to do what I need.

Comment: Set the current directory to the location of the files, zip files, pop the previous directory back. `PUSHD` and `POPD`

Comment: If you are just accepting the default location presented in the Microsoft Windows file browser, then yes, it suggests a subdirectory. You can change that by deleting the new directory name or putting in the location where you want the files to land.

Comment: Paul, are you talking about when you extract?  Because while that's true on a Windows PC, on a Mac (with Stuffit Deluxe, I believe) and evidently on Linux (unzip utility unknown so far, as our partner hasn't gotten us this info yet), it doesn't prompt, but just creates the folder with the name of the zip and drops files into it.

Comment: The WZUNZIP command will not create a directory if there is not one in the archive file. Please find out exactly which tool and command is being used that causes the undesired directory to be created.

Comment: Actually, WZUNZIP does (though it can be overridden by changing the default path upon extracting), but also Stuffit Deluxe on a Mac does, and some as yet unreported utility on a Linux box does too.  That's why I'm starting to think that WZZIP is innately forcing it somehow.